# What to do with extra video drivers?

Tags: 11.04, drivers, video, intel

I have 11.04 installed, and was poking around and saw that I had more than my Intel Video Drivers installed.

Do I need them?

What is the best way to "trim the fat"?

Comment: Where did you saw that you have more drivers ( screenshot would be nice )?

Answer (score 7):

If you're referring to display drivers that come with xorg, for example

```
xserver-xorg-video-apm
xserver-xorg-video-ark
xserver-xorg-video-ati
xserver-xorg-video-ati-dbg
xserver-xorg-video-chips
xserver-xorg-video-cirrus
xserver-xorg-video-displaylink
xserver-xorg-video-dummy
xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
...
```

You can remove some of them with `apt-get remove <driver_name>` if you want to but I'd advise against it. They are there in case you happen to change your display adapter and they don't take up very much space.

Removing one of them also removes `xserver-xorg-video-all` which is the metapackage containing all the display drivers that come with xorg. This shouldn't cause any problems, but I'd still play it safe and leave it alone.

Comment: Yeah.  In total, these drivers will eat on the order of 10 megs of storage space, and won't be loaded unless you need them.  You can remove them (I'd recommend leaving -vesa and -fbdev, as they're fallback drivers) but there's not much point.